# Regex split at all punctuations and English character sequences and keep delimiters with zhuyin in Python

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

How do I tokenise a string with a fixed set of symbols (zhuyin), punctuations, and English characters into zhuyin sequences (space delimited but sometimes joined by punctuations or English characters), individual punctuations, and English character sequences?

For a string as such

`"ㄉㄢˋＮＣＣㄗㄞˋ『ㄅㄠˇ ㄏㄨˋ』ㄍㄜ˙ ㄗ,ㄉㄜ˙「ㄑㄧㄢˊ ㄊㄧˊ」ㄒㄧㄚˋ。"`

How do I tokenise it into

`['ㄉㄢˋ', 'ＮＣＣ', ㄗㄞˋ', '『', 'ㄅㄠˇ', 'ㄏㄨˋ', '』', 'ㄍㄜ˙', 'ㄗ', ',', 'ㄉㄜ˙', '「', 'ㄑㄧㄢˊ',  'ㄊㄧˊ', '」', 'ㄒㄧㄚˋ', '。']`

I'm currently using list comprehension and regex pattern as such

`[seq for seq in re.split("([^\w˙])", input_str) if seq and seq != " "]`

but this fails to tokenise English character sequences and produces results like this

`['ㄉㄢˋＮＣＣㄗㄞˋ', '『', 'ㄅㄠˇ', 'ㄏㄨˋ', '』', 'ㄍㄜ˙', 'ㄗ', ',', 'ㄉㄜ˙', '「', 'ㄑㄧㄢˊ', 'ㄊㄧˊ', '」', 'ㄒㄧㄚˋ', '。']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `regex` module instead of `re` and use alternation between Zhuyin (or Bopomofo), Latin and punctuation marks. For example:

```
\p{Bopomofo}+[ˋˇ˙ˊ]?|\p{Latin}+|\p{P}
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W7onSo/6)

- `\p{Bopomofo}+` - Any one or more Zhuyin character.
- `[ˋˇ˙ˊ]?` - An optional character from the given characters.

  - `|` - Alternate (OR)
- `\p{Latin}+` - Any one or more Latin character (would capture the comma too).

  - `|` - Alternate (OR)
- `\p{P}` - Any kind of punctuation character.

---

```
import regex
text = 'ㄉㄢˋＮＣＣㄗㄞˋ『ㄅㄠˇ ㄏㄨˋ』ㄍㄜ˙ ㄗ,ㄉㄜ˙「ㄑㄧㄢˊ ㄊㄧˊ」ㄒㄧㄚˋ。'
lst = regex.findall(r'\p{Bopomofo}+[ˋˇ˙]?|\p{Latin}+|\p{P}', text)
print(lst)
```

Results in:

```
['ㄉㄢˋ', 'ＮＣＣ', 'ㄗㄞˋ', '『', 'ㄅㄠˇ', 'ㄏㄨˋ', '』', 'ㄍㄜ˙', 'ㄗ', ',', 'ㄉㄜ˙', '「', 'ㄑㄧㄢˊ', 'ㄊㄧˊ', '」', 'ㄒㄧㄚˋ', '。']
```